# Deployed version of MAUI app crashes after splash screen

Tags: maui, maui-ios, abp.io

I have a .NET MAUI app that I am able to run successfully in debug mode in both he iOS and Android versions. However, when I publish the app and deploy it to TestFlight, the app crashes immediately after the splash screen.

I originally created a version of the app in .NET 6, then .NET 7 and now .NET 8 (8.0.4) and with each version I get the exact same results. Is there a way to determine exactly what is causing the crash? I have tried all 3 linking methods for the app (Don't Link, Link SDK's only, Link All) and this hasn't changed the behavior.

Comment: Use logging or a crash reporting tool like Sentry or Raygun

Comment: Those applications don't seem to work with iOS apps built with .NET Maui and VS 2022

Comment: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/guides/maui/

Comment: Just connect you device to mac and open console. Then read what's happening when you tap on the app icon..

Answer (score 0):

We've encountered similar crash issues with iOS on published apps. Typically, if your app operates correctly in debug mode but faces issues in release mode, it may be utilizing a feature that requires the Interpreter. To address this, consider adding the following snippet to your project file to see if it resolves the issue:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <UseInterpreter Condition="$(TargetFramework.EndsWith('-ios'))">true</UseInterpreter>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For additional details, refer to the official documentation here:
[.NET MAUI: Mono Interpreter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/macios/interpreter?view=net-maui-8.0)

Further discussions on GitHub may also provide some context and background:

- [Discussion on .NET MAUI Issue #13019](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13019)
- [Comment on .NET MAUI Issue #12316](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12519)

As for identifying the cause of crashes, as suggested in the comments, employing a crash analytics service is advisable. Previously, we utilized AppCenter, but with Microsoft phasing it out, we've begun exploring alternatives like [Sentry](https://sentry.io/for/dotnet-maui/) and [NewRelic](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/new-relic-mobile-maui-dotnet/monitor-your-net-maui-application/).